# Standards for logging abstraction in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I'm a python newbie, and writing a small app which will require logging. I want the app to be portable, allowing other admins to configure its behaviour - particularly logging. The characteristics of the [logging lib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) seem to be controlled by the application code rather than the deployment/environment.

Java has [log4j](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j), PHP has [PSR-3](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md). Is there something equivalent for Python which would allow the system owner to inject their own logging capability?

Comment: don't think it's what you're after, but did you see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way, in my opinion, to achieve good flexibility, allowing admins to configure your logging settings is to use this config in a `ini` file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=stream_handler

[formatters]
keys=formatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=stream_handler

[handler_stream_handler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=formatter
args=(sys.stderr,)

[formatter_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s
```

After that you can read this configuration in your app:

```
import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

fileConfig('logging_config.ini')
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.debug('your debug message')
```

You can check more [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/logging/#example-configuration-via-an-ini-file).

Comment: Currently I'm using a ini file to handle stderr / syslog / email, although your solution is a lot more compact